# Add basic authentication to root of rails default website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I add basic authentication to the root of a rails website? In dev, I would want this to appear for localhost:3000; I was able to add basic auth to application controller which works for all controller methods; however, I would also like basic auth to be enforced for the root of the website (without redirecting root to a protected page).

In application_controller.rb, I currently have the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: ENV["USER_NAME"], password: ENV["PASSWORD"] if ENV["USER_NAME"].present? 


  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "would also like basic auth to be enforced for the root of the website"? You already added basic auth to application controller which will add auth to entire website.

Comment: Doesn't work, only protects controller methods, except for root

Comment: it works, not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: I'm using rails 4.2.6. I tested it a few times. When I hit a controller path, such as localhost:3000/videos, I get the basic auth logic. However, I can hit the homepage/root, and no auth dialog appears.

Comment: is `homepage/root` a static page in public directory?

Comment: it's the rails default "Welcome aboard" page that's part of a new rails project. In researching, it doesn't look like I can throw basic auth against the default page, which throws the "Welcome" page. I have to set a root in `routes.rb`, which is pointless, since I have one page to secure, and redirecting the user to that page makes it clear the URI I am trying to protect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have a root set in your routes.rb file. Try adding this to your routes file and you will have authentication on all your paths.

```
root "your_controller#some_action"
```

You can read more about it here: http://docs.railsbridge.org/intro-to-rails/setting_the_default_page

Comment: You are right, but doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to redirect the person to the page I'm trying to protect (removes obscurity from the security setup).

Comment: You have the authentication setup in the application controller, to get that to fire you need to first go through a controller. If you want authentication without going through a controller need to use a different type of authentication, maybe look into devise.

Comment: @user1322092, note that when you use root in your routes file the path in the url bar will be localhost:3000/ which would not reveal the path you are trying to keep private

Answer (score 0):

As you Said :

> I was able to add basic auth to application controller which works for all controller methods.

I doubt that you have controller#method route to the root path, So when you send a request to localhost:3000 you don't trigger any action then nothing gets handled by your basic authentication in this case.

Comment: You are right, but that doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to redirect to the page I'm trying to protect (only 1 page on site). Yes, I could create a dummy page... still want to see if it's possible.